# CONST_EXPR in Angular2 RC.0

Tags: angular

I was using CONST_EXPR in beta releases via;

```
import {CONST_EXPR} from 'angular/src/facade/lang';
```

But this is not working with Angular2 RC.0, is there way to import it from somewhere or is there a viable replacement. I was using it to integrate with ngModel in my input components to create a value accessor e.g.

```
const INPUTSWITCH_VALUE_ACCESSOR: Provider = CONST_EXPR(
new Provider(NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, {
    useExisting: forwardRef(() => InputSwitch),
    multi: true
}));
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think `CONST_EXPR` was just a wrapper for required translation of `const` for `ts2dart`. It seems they got rid of this recently. There is no need to make this const in TypeScript.

See also https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/8227/files